# Obtaining width of WiFi networks programmatically

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

How do I obtain such information? After digging around I was able to find the opcodes used with WinAPI

[WLAN_INTF_OPCODE enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706886.aspx)

However I couldn't find the necessary means of getting information on the channel width.

Comment: Does this contain the information you need? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706015(v=vs.85).aspx Get it from `WlanQueryInterface` with `wlan_intf_opcode_current_connection`

Comment: It appears that only specifies the connection type (b/g/n/ac) and such, I can't really get the channel width from that

Comment: @ImQ009: It does not appear that `WlanQueryInterface()` supports what you are looking for. You will have to look somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is however the fact I don't know where to look

Comment: I hope this gets a real answer someday. Procedurally getting the frequency band, channel number, and channel width was so easy on OSX. Now trying to do the same thing on Windows, I've had to do more work to infer the band and channel number from center freq, but I haven't been able to figure out width.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Windows Native Wifi Api does not present the channel width information directy. But this (as well as many other parameters) can be obtained from the Wi-Fi Beacon frames transmitted by the access points.

This information can be accessed by the WlanApi WlanGetNetworkBssList function, which returns a list of WLAN_BSS_ENTRY structures (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wlanapi/ns-wlanapi-wlan_bss_entry). Via that structure you have access to all the Information Elements present in the received beacons, but you have to parse that information yourself.

I needed this feature in the project I'm working on, so I found a Python wrapper library for the WlanApi (win32wifi) and added this feature to it. You can check it out on github (https://github.com/opetryna/win32wifi/commit/35bc65df12ae8e3c579f4e867b3bfcadfb6e072a).